# How to fetch data Firestore subcollection Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I want to get data from Firebase Firestore subcollection for recyclerView. But I dont know if I write codes correctly or no. I also checked another variant with another collection without any subcollection and I see there I succesfully get data from Firestore. But with subcollection part which is i uploaded it with image below I can not fetch data and my recyclerView is empty.How can i fix that? Thanks in advance

Here is my Firebase Firestore collection
[image]

Here is my Firebase Firestore subcollection
[image]

And my codes

```
class Posts : AppCompatActivity(), RecAdapterPosts.ClickListener {
    var modalList : ArrayList<ModalImageList> = ArrayList()
    private lateinit var binding: PostsBinding
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private var userAdapter = RecAdapterPosts(modalList, this)
    private var db = Firebase.firestore

    private var database: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = PostsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = (binding.root)
        setContentView(view)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        gridPosts.adapter = userAdapter
        gridPosts.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this,2)
        get_information()
    }

    private fun get_information() {
        val cu = auth.currentUser!!.uid
        database.collection("İmagesPosts",).document(cu!!).collection("ImagesList").orderBy("date",
            Query.Direction.DESCENDING
        ).addSnapshotListener { snaphot, exception ->
            if (exception != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, exception.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            } else {
                if (snaphot != null) {
                    if (!snaphot.isEmpty) {
                        val documents = snaphot.documents
                        modalList.clear()
                        for (document in documents) {
                            val imgUrl = document.get("downloadUs") as String
                            val imgName = document.get("imgName") as String

                            val download_post = ModalImageList(
                                imgUrl,
                                imgName,

                            )
                            modalList.add(download_post)
                        }
                    }
                    userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This path `database.collection("İmagesPosts",).document(cu!!).collection("ImagesList")` looks fine at first glance. If you set a breakpoint on the `if (exception != null) {` and run the code in the debugger, does it reach that line? If so, if you then step through the code in the debugger and inspect each variable on each line, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Thans you two for advance i found the issue that with my modul class